# Removing an area from a cuboid shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a Bar top and it has an indentation on its underside, I have tried to set loop-cuts and extrude all relevant pieces but it keeps coming out less than stellar. What are some faster ways to remove an area from a shape in blender?

[image: image to be modeled]

Looking at the dark silvery colour under the countertop

As you can see below, I tried using loop cuts but it hasn't lead to any success for me. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  to add a loop cut.
<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide.
<kbd>G</kbd> to move/grab.
<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> to move along global Y axis.
<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select an edge loop.
<kbd>E</kbd> to extrude.
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to switch the selection context.
<kbd>B</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to box deselect.

1. #### Double Geometry  (not that good)

   Add two loop cuts. Edge Slide the lower loop cuts upwards. Deselect the back vertices and select the lower ones. Move them back along Y. 
   [image]
2. #### N-Gon  (not that good)

   Delete the side faces, add two loopcuts and move the vertices together. Move the lower face along Y. Make the missing face <kbd>F</kbd>.
   [image]
3. #### Extrusion

   Add one loop cut. Select the upper face. Extrude the upper face.  [image]
4. #### Multiple meshes

   Duplicate the geometry, move and scale it accordingly.
   [image]

> Now, although you probably had #3 in mind, I'd advise you to think about the benefits of #4. In the real world, these object would be two separate pieces as well, with separate materials.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the tutorials, I was thinking about using 3 but 4 seems like a shout!